# Regular Expression for 3 Alphabets followed by one space followed by one digit

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a string like this:

```
ABC 123
```

I tried using this regular expression in my PHP code:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}[ ]{3}[0-9]{3}&/', $class_code)
```

but it seems to match even strings like this one:

```
ABC jsfdkajf 123
```

It should give false for this string, but it's giving a match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ampersand `&` at the end should likely be a dollar sign `$`.

Answer (score 0):

This regEx should work for you:

```
^\w{3}\s?\d{3}$
```

example code:

```
<?php

    $str = "ABC jsfdkajf 123";  //"ABC 123"
    if(!preg_match('/^\w{3}\s?\d{3}$/', $str))
        echo "no ";
    echo "match";

?>
```

output:

```
no match //match
```

regEx explanation:

```
^\w{3}\s?\d{3}$
```

- **^** assert position at start of a line
- **\w{3}** match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- Quantifier: **{3}** Exactly 3 times
- **\s?** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- Quantifier: **?** Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **\d{3}** match a digit [0-9]
- Quantifier: **{3}** Exactly 3 times
- **$** assert position at end of a line

**Useful regEx links:**

- [regEx chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions)
- [regEx cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)
- [test your regEx!](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that you want to match exactly 3 spaces, but you have just 1 in `ABC 123`.

In PHP, you can use Unicode character sets, I'd go with them.

Regex: `^\p{Lu}{3}\p{Zs}+\p{N}{3}$`

- `^` - Start of line
- `\p{Lu}{3}` - Three uppercase letters
- `\p{Zs}+` - Any number of spaces (adjust as needed, also includes hard space)
- `\p{N}{3}` - Three numbers exactly
- `$` - Line end

Here is a sample PHP code:

```
$re = "/^\p{Lu}{3}\p{Zs}+\p{N}{3}$/"; 
$str = "ABC 123"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output [and a link to a sample program](http://goo.gl/X0TxZi):

```
[0] => ABC 123
```

Answer (score 0):

For your regex you have to change:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}[ ]{3}[0-9]{3}&/', $class_code)
```

To

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}[ ][0-9]{3}$/', $class_code)
                                 ^--- use this instead &
```

Btw, you could use a regex like this:

```
^[A-Za-z]{3} \d{3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or using the insensitive flag:

```
^[a-z]{3} \d{3}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY8hN5/2)**

```
$re = "/^[a-z]{3} \\d{3}$/mi"; 
$str = "ABC 123\nABC 1\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Another observation is that you posted *"3 Alphabets followed by one space followed by one digit"*, so if you want only ONE digits at the end you could use:

```
^[A-Za-z]{3} \d$
```